# Spacing in <li> tags with display table-cell

Tags: html, css

I've four `li` tags and they all contains images in it. Now, I want to show images vertically center and for this I've used `display: table-cell` for all `li` and on image I've used vertical-align middle. But margin isn't working when I am trying to put spacing between li's.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WENN/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="achievements">
     <h2>Our <span>Achievements</span></h2>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="images/award-1.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/award-2.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/award-3.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/award-4.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.achievements ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.achievements ul li {
    min-width: 304px;
    min-height: 208px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #aaa;
    color: #000;
    margin-right: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    max-width: 303px;
    background: #fff;
    font-family:'gafata';
    padding-top: 32px;
    line-height: 23px;
    text-align:center;
}
.achievements ul li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) to add spacing between the cells.

In order for this to have an effect on the table, the [`border-collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) value should be `separate` (the default value) as opposed to `collapse`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7crq2/)

```
.achievements ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display:table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

If you want to center the table, simply add `margin:0 auto`. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/fEF75/show/)

Comment: Thanks josh, this worked but can all li display in center as well? I've tried text-align:center; in ul but it's not working.